# Identities involving Littlewood–Richardson coefficients?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, schur-functions

I am not aware of that many identities that involve several Littlewood–Richardson coefficients.
One recent identity, is a generating function as sum of squares of LR-coefficients,
due to [Harris and Willenbring](https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/littlewoodRichardson.htm#harrisWillenbring) in [Sums of squares of Littlewood–Richardson coefficients and $\operatorname{GL}_n$-harmonic polynomials](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-1590-3_11). This identity is really interesting.

There is also a relation between two sums of LR-coefficients,
due to Coquereaux and Zuber, but I find this less interesting for this question.

**So my question is, are there some interesting relations involving (potentially weighted) sums of LR-coefficients?**

Comment: You can take the definition of the LR coefficients $s_{\mu}(x_1,\ldots) s_{\nu}(x_1,\ldots) = \sum_{\lambda} c^{\lambda}_{\mu, \nu} s_{\lambda}(x_1,\ldots)$ and do any of the several nice specializations of Schur functions to get such an identity.

Comment: There are other identities involving LR coefficients which follow from exceptional equalities among skew Schur functions (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602634) or sums of products of pairs of Schur functions (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004113), but these are of a different flavor.

Comment: For another example: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.06128

Comment: For a  mild generalization of the Harris-Willenbring identity, see Problem 92(d) at https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ch7supp.pdf.  Problem 91 also has some identities involving $c^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ together with $f^\lambda$, $f^\mu$, and $f^\nu$.

Comment: The OP was asked in relation to some new results which have been finally made available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.11115.  

In this paper, a relation involving the Jack Littlewood-Richardson coefficients of the following form is shown
$\sum_{\gamma \supset \mu \cup \nu}  c_{\mu\nu}^{\gamma}(\alpha)  f_{\gamma,\mu,\nu}(u)  = g_{\mu,\nu}(u)$, where $f_{\gamma,\mu,\nu}(u)$ and $g_{\mu,\nu}(u)$ are explict rational functions in a variable $u$.

Comment: The culmination of this work, in which Per and I prove some new cases of the Stanley conjecture, is now out: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.13870

Answer (score 4):

We looked into this with Greta and Damir in [On the largest Kronecker and Littlewood–Richardson coefficients](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04693).  Unfortunately, other than the Harris–Willenbring identity we didn't find much.  For our bounds we even had to invent a new (not too difficult) LR-identity which follows from the *skew Cauchy identity* (it's Lemma 5.1 in the paper):
$$
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \left( c^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}\right)^2 \, = \, \sum_{\alpha, \beta,
\gamma, \delta}  c^{\mu}_{\alpha\gamma}  c^{\mu}_{\alpha \delta} 
c^{\nu}_{\beta\gamma} c^{\nu}_{\beta \delta}.
$$